# Undefined method `send_reset_email' for Notifier:Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, sendgrid

I am attempting to add email notifications to my rails app. I just finished following the [SendGrid Documentation](https://sendgrid.com/docs/Integrate/Frameworks/rubyonrails.html) for Ruby on Rails.

Here's what I have so far:

**mailers/notifier.rb**

```
class Notifier < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "automailer@fitnessentials.net"

  def send_reset_email(user)
    @user = user
    mail( :to => @user.email,
    :subject => 'Thanks for signing up for our amazing app' )
  end
end
```

**It's use in my app**

```
class ResetTokensController < ApplicationController
    def new
        if request.post?
            @user = User.find_by(email: params[:email])
            if @user && @user.id > 0
                @token = ResetToken.new
                @token.user_id = @user.id
                @token.token = BCrypt::Password.create("Aw3s0m3S@lt")
                Notifier.send_reset_email(@token.user).deliver
                if @token.save
                    redirect_to '/forgotpassword/sent'
                end
            else
            end
        end
    end
end
```

**and the configuration in environment.rb**

ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :user_name => '********',
  :password => '********',
  :domain => '*********.net',
  :address => 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
  :port => 587,
  :authentication => :plain,
  :enable_starttls_auto => true
}

However, when I run the app, I'm getting this error:

```
NoMethodError in ResetTokensController#new
undefined method `send_reset_email' for Notifier:Class
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "send_reset_email" method is not a class-level method. Try:

```
Notifier.new.send_reset_email(@token.user).deliver
```

Comment: That got me this: `private method `new' called for Notifier:Class`. Any other ideas?

Comment: Hmmm... it's plausible you've got a name-clash. "Notifier" is a very generic name. Perhaps you could call it `ResetTokensNotifer` or `FitnessEssentialsNotifier` - anything so long as it's more specific?

Comment: Ah, the magic internals of Rails/Ruby... they do sometimes magically get in your way :)